# HTML Comments Extracter

Tags: html, security, parsing

I am well aware that parsing HTML with regex has its many caveats and vociferous opponents. So rather than trying to re-invent the wheel, I'm looking for a tool that I can point to a web page and say "Get me the comments, b*tch".

Anyone able to advise?

I was reading some OWASP documentation or a security blog, and I'm almost certain I saw a tool performing this task. Google has been zero help unfortunately.

Cheers

Comment: What language? Also, what kind of content would you like to extract? All of the text? Some text? Images? Do you have an example page?

Comment: @Pekka, you can't do it in HTML? ohmygosh.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a Java solution try [HTMLParser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/) and look for [RemarkNode](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/htmlparser/nodes/RemarkNode.html)s.

Answer (score 0):

Mhhhhh...I think a search in Google with the OS you use and some clever keyword gives you all you want. For UNIX based system looks at: [parse HTML with SED and PERL](http://www.computing.net/answers/unix/help-parsing-html-file-using-perl-/7851.html)

For Windows OS I think you can search something with VBS (VBScript).